# Optimize LINQ Query for use with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: vb.net, httphandler, jquery-autocomplete

I'm working on building an HTTPHandler that will serve up plain text for use with jQuery Autocomplete.  I have it working now except for when I insert the first bit of text it does not take me to the right portion of the alphabet.

Example: If I enter `Ne`

my drop down returns

> Nlabama
>   Arkansas

Notice the "N" from `Ne` and the "labama" from "Alabama"

As I type the third character `New`, then the jQuery returns the "N" section of the results.

My current code looks like this

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    ''# the page ContentType is plain text
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

    ''# store the querystring as a variable'
    Dim qs As Nullable(Of Integer) = Integer.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("ID"), Nothing)

    ''# use the RegionsDataContext'
    Using RegionDC As New DAL.RegionsDataContext

        ''# create a (q)uery variable'
        Dim q As Object

        ''# if the querystring PID is not blank'
        ''# then we want to return results based on  the PID'
        If Not qs Is Nothing Then
            ''# that fit within the Parent ID'
            q = (From r In RegionDC.bt_Regions _
                    Where r.PID = qs _
                   Select r.Region).ToArray

            ''# now we loop through the array'
            ''# and write out the ressults'
            For Each item In q
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(item & vbCrLf)
            Next

        End If


    End Using
End Sub
```

So where I'm at now is the fact that I stumbled on the "[Part](http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/05/05/auto-complete-field-with-jquery-json-php/)" portion of the Autocomplete method whereby I should only return information that is contained within the Part.

My question is, how would I implement this concept into my HTTPHandler without doing a fresh SQLQuery on every character change?  IE: I do the SQL Query on the **QueryString("ID")**, and then on every subsequent load of the same ID, we just filter down the "Part".

http://www.example.com/ReturnRegions.axd?ID=[someID]&Part=[string]

Comment: Also, in the article I posted, the guy talks about using JSON, and I honestly don't know the first thing about JSON or how it would correspond to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my jQuery library to use the jQuery-UI and then built my iHttpHandler using a Singleton object in order to avoid hitting the database on every page load.  The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931877/cant-get-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-with-external-json/2933668#2933668) seems to be working well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the `part` from the querystring and use it in the `Where` clause to filter only Regions that start with it AND have the appropriate ID.

ToArray is not necessary

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately I was still hitting the database over and over.  I figured out what I was looking for after a lot of digging.  Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction tho. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931877/cant-get-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-with-external-json/2933668#2933668